# Is there any "native" way to check for disk errors/failure?

Tags: linux, monitoring, storage

Currently I check for disk failures using a real hodgepodge of checking syslog for filesystem errors, raid controller/HBA burp errors, and actively writing a file to disk, checking its contents, and deleting it.  The results of these are adapted to whatever monitoring solution(s) we have in place, but it's generally a crummy way to do things.  The way XFS reports errors is different from ext4 or zfs, or whatever.

What I feel like should exist by now is something like `/sys/block/sdc/write_error_count`, a counter that would just increment any time a block write fails for any reason.  A `read_error_count` analogue would exist on that side as well.  A similar thing could exist for filesystems (as opposed to raw block devices).

Does anything like this actually exist in Linux now?  If not, is there any truly canonical way to check for failed storage?

Answer (score 3):

How about [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) and specifically the `smartctl` command? `smartctl` report you back the SMART statistics from the hard drive and you'll see the number of errors, number of hours the device has been on, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've used smartmontools for years, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be very accurate in my experience, especially for newer disks that aren't in its DB.